# Laravel set restrict to inserted values into database

Tags: php, laravel

I am developing a social network with laravel 5.3
I defines a relationship table containing two columns called `one_id` and `two_id`.
Say, if `user_one` sends a friend  request to `user_two` for the first time, a new record will be inserted into relationship table with `one_id` and `two_id` changed to these two persons' ids.
Of course,these two ids cannot be the same.But I don't figure out how to set the restrict with laravel.

I comes up with two solutions now:

1. Setting a insert listener,when a insert happens laravel will do some
   check.
2. Setting check in the `up` method in `create_realtions_table` when migrate

Are these two ways going to work? If so,how ?

Comment: how are `one_id` and `two_id` populated? you can use unique validation.

Comment: @SanzeebAryal unique is used for two records not for one record

Comment: @SanzeebAryal A validation may works But I want restriction when building table.

Comment: @SanzeebAryal Yes. one_id must be different from two_id in one row

Comment: Basically the `one_id` and `two_id` are always different, because they are generated from parent table `users`'s autoincrementing primary key `id`. You can try this validation  `return [
            'one_id'  => 'unique:one_id,two_id',
            'two_id'  => 'unique:one_id,two_id',
        ];`

Comment: @SanzeebAryal Ok I will give it a shot Thank you